# Multivariable limits using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

We are supposed to prove that  $\lim_{x,y \to 2,1}(3x+4y)=10$

Therefore, we need to show that $|3x+4y-10|=|3(x-2)+4(y-1)|<\epsilon$, such that for every $\epsilon$, there is some $\delta$,such that $\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2}<\delta.$

Now, my textbook states: "if we take $|x-2|<\delta$ and $|y-1|<\delta$, we have

$|3x+4y-10|=|3(x-2)+4(y-1)|<3|x-2|+4|y-1|<3\delta +4\delta=7\delta<\epsilon$.

So we can chose $\delta <\epsilon/7$, and the proof is finished."

**Question**:

My only concern is with the statement: *if we take $|x-2|<\delta$ and $|y-1|<\delta$*. This supposedly accounts for the fact that $\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2}<\delta.$ (i.e, the point $(x,y)$ is inside the circle centered at $(2,1)$ of radius $\delta$ ).

However, $|x-2|<\delta$ and $|y-1|<\delta$ only tells us that the point $(x,y)$ is within the interior of the square *circumscribing* the required circle. It does not necessarily imply that the point $(x,y)$ is within the circle.

**How then, can we justify the fact that $\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2}<\delta.$?**

Comment: You have typed $\sqrt {(x-2)^{2}+(y-2)^{2}}$ instead of $ \sqrt {(x-2)^{2}+(y-1)^{2}}$. Note that $(x,y)$ is tending to $(2,1)$.

Comment: Inside every square there's a disk, and vice-versa. So there's no difference between using $\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2}$ or $\max\{|x-2|,|y-1|\}$.

Comment: You can always draw a circle containing a square or a circle contained by a square.

Answer (score 3):

You are confused about the definition of limit. We want $\delta$ such that $\sqrt {(x-2)^{2}+(y-1)^{2}} <\delta$ implies $|3x+4y-10|  <\epsilon$. Choose $\delta$ the way the book suggests. Now start with $(x,y)$ such that $\sqrt {(x-2)^{2}+(y-1)^{2}} <\delta$. Then $|x-2| <\delta$ and $|y-1| <\delta$. Hence, $|3x+4y-10|  <\epsilon$.

[I Have used the fact that $|x-2| \leq  \sqrt {(x-2)^{2}+(y-1)^{2}}$ and  $|y-1| \leq  \sqrt {(x-2)^{2}+(y-1)^{2}}$].